# Unable to compare numbers with v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to do some styling based on condition from the binding value using v-if

I tried using the v-if but I was unable to get the result. I also tried ternary operator in vue it dint work

```
<table>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="cat in this.table_data">
                    <th v-for="(value, key) in data">
                        <div v-if="key == 'Projected Utilization'">
                            <div v-if="0.0 <= value ">
                                    <td style="background-color: coral">{{value}}</td>
                            </div>
                            <div v-else>

                                <td style="background-color: green">{{value}}</>       
                </div>
                </tbody> 
            </table>
```

I have my data in the table_data and data contains a key value pair and I have checked that it had values

but the code always ends up in the false condition after many searches i thought to ask the community. point me if I am doing anything wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: The key you're referencing is an index of `data`, since you used `key` as your index parameter in the for loop. What you probably mean to do is check `v-if="value.something == 'Projected Utilization'"`.

Comment: the problem was I manipulating the values and adding a string this made comparison false always. thanks for the support

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check that there is no close tag of the **TR** element and the use of **this** is incorrect, so the valid markup is:

### Example 1: (check https://codepen.io/matiasperrone/pen/JQdRzW)

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="cat in table_data" :key="cat">
        <th v-for="(value, key) in data" :key="value">
          <div :style="{ backgroundColor:  key === 'Projected Utilization' ? 'transparent' : 0.0 <= value ? 'coral' : 'green' }">{{ value }}</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      table_data: [{name: 'data1'}, {name: 'data2'},],
      data: {key1: 1001, key2: -1003, "Projected Utilization": 100}
    }
  }
});
```